# Fastest way to allocate temporary elements (knowing maximum number) in a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, std

in a function I need to store some integers  in a vector. The function is called a lot of times. I know that they are less then 10 but the number is variable for each call of the function. What is the choice to have better performances?

In example I found that this:

```
std::vector<int> list(10)
std::vector<int>::iterator it=list.begin();
unsigned int nume_of_elements_stored;

for ( ... iterate on some structures ... ){
    if (... a specific condition ...){
         *it= integer from structures ;
         it++;
         nume_of_elements_stored++;
     }
}
```

is slower than:

```
std::vector<int> list;
unsigned int num_of_elements_stored(0);

for ( ... iterate on some structures ... ){
    if (... a specific condition ...){
         list.push_back( integer from structures )
     }
}
num_of_elements_stored=list.size();
```

Comment: I would not be shocked if a `reserve` + `emplace_back` implementation out-performed *both* of those.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Given that what he's putting in the vector is `int`s, chances of `emplace_back` making a difference vs. copying strikes me as pretty minimal.

Comment: Usually you don't store the number of elements in a `vector` separately. Just use `size()`.

Comment: I have to ask - why do you think that array creation and destroying (with arryas of this magnitude) are a performance bottleneck?  Perhaps if you added that this was being done a gazillion times per second or something, it might be more of an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go down an extremely uncool route here. At the risk of being crucified, I would suggest that `std::vector` isn't so great here. An exception would be if you get lucky with the memory allocator and get that temporal locality through the allocator that creating and destroying a bunch of teeny `vectors` normally wouldn't provide.

**Wait!**

Before people kill me, I want to say that `vector` is awesome, generally speaking, as one of the most well-rounded data structures available. But when you're looking at a hotspot like this (hopefully with a profiler) as a result of creating a bunch of teeny `vectors` repeatedly in a tight loop, that's where this kind of straightforward usage of `vector` can bite you.

The trouble is that it's a heap-allocated structure (basically a dynamic array), and when we're dealing with a boatload of teeny arrays like this, we really want to use that often-cached memory at the top of the stack that's so cheap to allocate/free when we can.

One way to mitigate this is to reuse the same vector across repeated calls. Store it in the outside caller function's scope and pass it in by reference, `clear` it, do your `push_backs`, rinse and repeat. It's worth noting that `clear` doesn't free any memory in the vector, so it keeps that former capacity around (useful here when we want to reuse the same memory and play to temporal locality).

But here we can play to that stack. As a simplified example (using C-style code that isn't very kosher in C++ or even bothers with exception-safety, but easier to illustrate):

```
int stack_mem[32];
int num = 0;
int cap = 32;
int* ptr = stack_mem;

for ( ... iterate on some structures ... )
{
    if (... a specific condition ...)
    {
         if (num == cap)
         {
             cap *= 2;
             int* new_ptr = static_cast<int*>(malloc(cap * sizeof(int)));
             memcpy(new_ptr, ptr, num * sizeof(int));
             if (ptr != stack_mem)
                  free(ptr);
             ptr = new_ptr;
         }
         ptr[num++] = your_int;
    }
}

if (ptr != stack_mem)
     free(ptr);
```

Of course if you use something like this, you should properly wrap it in a reusable class template that does bounds-checking, doesn't use `memcpy`, has exception-safety, a formal push_back method, emplace_back, copy ctor, move ctor, swap, possibly a fill ctor, range ctor, erase, range erase, insert, range insert, size, empty, iterators/begin/end, uses placement new to avoid requiring copy assignment or default ctor, etc.

The solution uses the stack when `N <= 32` (can use a different number suited for your common-case needs) and then switches to heap when exceeded. This allows it to handle your common case scenarios efficiently but also not just go kablooey in those rare case scenarios when `N` might be huge in some pathological case. That makes it somewhat comparable to variable-length arrays in C (something I actually wish we had in C++, at least until `std::dynarray` is available) but without the stack overflow tendencies VLAs could have since it switches to heap in rare case scenarios.

I applied all these standard-compliant formalities with a structure based on this idea with a class template that accepts `<T, FixedN>`, and now use it almost as much as `vector` since I work with so many cases like this with teeny arrays being repeatedly created that should, in the vast majority of common cases, fit on the stack (but always with those ultra rare exceptional possibilities). It wiped off many profiler hotspots I was getting related to memory off the map.

... but applying this basic idea might give you quite a boost. You can apply that kind of effort above of wrapping it into a safe container preserving C++ object semantics if it pays off in your measurements, and I think it should quite a bit in your case.

Comment: Agreed.  `int list[10];` with  `int numInts` set to the number of integer values actually used is going to be a **LOT** faster than `std::vector<int> list(10);`

Comment: Folly [small_vector](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/small_vector.md) might be of interest.

Comment: It is a very good solution, but I need to manipulate after the list vector. So it is safer for me to keep a vector then an array!

Comment: @TommasoFerrari That folly `small_vector` might be of great interest if you are really in a performance crunch.  It can give you that safety and Sequence-compliant interface making it easily interchangeable with `vector`. It looks almost identical to what I ended up implementing quite a long ago in a proprietary codebase to optimize teeny-vector hotspots, and might actually be even better (mine was designed for C++03).

Comment: @TommasoFerrari Both vectors and arrays are just ordered sets of values.  Any operation that you can do to one, you can do to the other.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, but after it would be the opportunity of erasing some elements. Vectrors fits a lot with what I have to do.

Comment: @TommasoFerrari To remove an element from an array of `int`:  `numElems--; for ( int i = elementToRemove; i < numElems; i++) { array[i]=array[i+1]; }`  Note the location of braces after the `for` statement.  Bounds checking is left off in this example in the interest of brevity.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with sort of a middle ground:

```
std::vector<int> list;
list.reserve(10);
```

...and the rest could be pretty much like your second version. To be honest, however, it's probably open to question whether this will really make a lot of difference though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have the knowledge that at most you will keep 10 items, is not it simpler and faster an simple C array of 10 elements? Something like `int list [10]`. Why to use vector?

Comment: @lrleon: because (among other things) an array doesn't keep track of its own size. Under the circumstances, I suppose he could use it, but I'd have to be extremely desperate for extra speed before I descended to using an array (and I'm not at all sure I'd get any extra speed anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you use static vector it will be allocated only once. 
First example works slower because it allocates and destroys vector each call.

Comment: I found what you say it is not true. I tried to construct the vector list in a class and define the function as a class method. It seems to be more slow than the first solution. I think that in an optimized compiling the compiler knows how to manage the memory.